# como puedo afectar a un solo elemento con forEach en un nodeList

Tags: javascript, html, html5

hola tengo el siguiente codigo el problema es que al iterar con forEach afecta a todos los elementos del nodeList que son 3 como podria hacer para afectar solo al que le afecta el evento

```
const $projects = document.querySelectorAll(".projects__grid__element")

$projects.forEach( (project,index) => {
    
    addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
        
        // const $projectDescription= project.querySelector(project[index]);
        // $projectDescription.style.display= "flex"
    });
    addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
        // const $projectDescription= project.querySelector(".projects__grid__element__description");
        // $projectDescription.style.display = "none"
    });
})
```

Comment: event.target.style.display= "flex"

Comment: Si ya resolviste tu problema, ponlo como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El detector de eventos se adjunta con window. Pero como deseab que el detector de eventos se adjunte a cada project, debi usar project.addEventListener. como esto:

```
const $projects = document.querySelectorAll(".projects__grid__element")

$projects.forEach( (project,index) => {
    
    project.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
        
        // const $projectDescription= project.querySelector(project[index]);
        // $projectDescription.style.display= "flex"
    });
    project.addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
        // const $projectDescription= project.querySelector(".projects__grid__element__description");
        // $projectDescription.style.display = "none"
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera es usando el mismo evento `museover` sobre el cual se aplica. Se hace con [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/target) y el ejemplo siguiente.

De esta forma el código es más limpio y simplificado

```js
const $projects = document.querySelectorAll(".projects__grid__element")

$projects.forEach( (e) => {

e.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
//event.target.style.display = "flex";
event.target.style.opacity = "1";
});

e.addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
//event.target.style.display = "none";
event.target.style.opacity = ".3"
});

})
```

```css
            
div {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
max-width: 400px;
height: 100%;
list-style: none;
margin: auto;
}

div li {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
margin: 1rem;
padding: 1rem;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0,128,0, 0.9);
opacity: .3
}
```

```html
            
<div>
<li class="projects__grid__element">Este es una lista</li>
<li class="projects__grid__element">Este es una lista</li>
</div>
```

Comment: no es lo que buscaba ya que tengo un div sobre otro div y necesitaba que uno se muestre encima del otro cuando lanzaba el evento mouseover ademas con e.target funciona cuando tengo un solo elemento pero cuando tiene dos hijos y ese hijo tiene otros dos hijo no es tan sencillo creo o me equivoco?, igual ya lo solucione especificando con e.addEventListener(... no estaba especificando el e por eso tomaba todo el node list. igual muchas gracias por tu ayudaa :)